# check whether 'if' statement or 'elif' has else block or not in Python

Tags: python, logic

In following code 'if' statement doesn't have 'else' .So I needed a function that tell me whether 'if' has 'else' block or not

```
if a==b:
    return True
```

In following code 'if' statement has 'elif' .'elif' statement doesn't have its 'else' block.So I needed a function that tell me whether 'elif' has 'else' block or not.

```
if a==b:
    return True
elif a>b:
    return False
```

Comment: Why do you need that?  How do you intend to use it?

Comment: I need that for semantic mutation testing.I have to append 'else' block after 'if' condition if it does't have its else block.

Comment: Look at the `ast` module in the standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to parse the python file's text yourself, I'll give you some hints:

1. Read line by line
2. Check if there's an 'if' at the start of a line using `.startswith("if")`
3. If there is, record the indentation level of the line
4. If you find a line where the indentation level drops below what you recorded already, or you find another if statement (at the same level), or you arrive at the EoF, you know that if statement didn't have
5. Same thing for elifs
6. Also, use recursion for ifs within ifs.

Comment: your solution is correct but I want some in-built function or 3rd party lib